# Runtime error 3151 when calling Oracle stored procedure with IN parameter

Tags: oracle, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I am trying to calling Oracle procedure in MS Access. Procedure is having IN parameter and i am unable to call it, every time i am getting "ODBC call failed" error. While running the Oracle procedure without having any IN or OUT parameter, that is successfully calling and performing the desired result. I just want to know how to call parameters in Access for Oracle procedure.

In the following code i have one Oracle procedure `trt` and `P_FILENAME` is IN parameter and i want it that IN parameter `P_FILENAME` will be given by user only. In that `trt` procedure i am trying to import file through utl_file function and it is working fine while i am running SQL Developer while calling it in Access i am not able to do so.

```
On Error GoTo trap


Dim db As Database
   Dim LSProc As QueryDef
   Dim LSQL As String

   Set db = CurrentDb()

   Set LSProc = db.CreateQueryDef("")

   'SQL to call stored procedure (with parameters)
    LSQL = "BEGIN trt ('" & P_FILENAME & "' )"
    'LSQL = "Begin TRT ('BUSMAY2014.csv')"
    LSQL = LSQL & "; END;"


   'Use {Microsoft ODBC for Oracle} ODBC connection
  LSProc.Connect = "ODBC;DSN=ODM_UNCT;UID=ODM_UNCTLD;PWD=****;SERVER=******"
   LSProc.SQL = LSQL
   LSProc.ReturnsRecords = False
   LSProc.ODBCTimeout = 0

   LSProc.Execute
   'DoCmd.RunSQL ("EXEC trt " & P_FILENAME)
 CallSProc = True
 Exit Sub
trap:
        Dim MyError As Error
      MsgBox Errors.Count
      For Each MyError In DBEngine.Errors
        With MyError
          MsgBox .Number & " " & .Description
        End With
      Next MyError

End Sub
```

MS ACCESS is the front-end and Oracle is back end. 
TRT is Procedure name 
P_FILENAME is IN parameter of the procedure

Answer (score 1):

The following code works for me:

```vbs
Dim db As DAO.Database, LSProc As DAO.QueryDef
Set db = CurrentDb
Set LSProc = db.CreateQueryDef("")
LSProc.Connect = "ODBC;DSN=ODM_UNCT;UID=GORD;PWD=whatever;"
LSProc.SQL = "BEGIN TRT('HelloFromAccess'); END;"
LSProc.ReturnsRecords = False
LSProc.Execute dbFailOnError
Set LSProc = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```